# How to escape &quot; without using gsub

Tags: html, json, ruby, parsing, html-parsing

```rb
x = JSON.parse(meta[:phone_number])

output = "&quot;(982) xxx-xxxx&quot;]"
```

I just want the phone number.

I can do this `JSON.parse(meta[:phone_number]).gsub('&quot;', '"')`

This works fine but it is not compatible with every version we have.

I want something which works every where and very simple.

Comment: Can you please provide a list of example inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: What do you mean it's "not compatible with every version we have"?

Comment: Use the URI or CGI standard library modules to unescape HTML.

Answer (score 1):

### Check Your Data

First of all, your data (as originally posted) does not resolve to a normalized phone number. Even with the HTML entity `&quot;` unescaped, you'll end up with:

> ```
> "(982) xxx-xxxx"]
> ```

This has embedded double-quotes and a trailing square bracket inside the string. This is probably not what you intend. If you can, make sure you aren't putting a bandage over the problem by working around it in your JSON receiver rather than in your upstream API.

### Unescaping HTML Entities with the CGI Module

Meanwhile, if your goal is primarily to unescape HTML entities in a string, you can do that with the [CGI#unescape_html](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-unescapeHTML) method from the Ruby standard library. For example, using a corrected input string without the trailing square bracket:

```
require 'cgi'

phone_str = "&quot;(982) xxx-xxxx&quot;"
CGI.unescape_html(phone_str).delete ?"
#=> "(982) xxx-xxxx"
```

Note that simply unescaping still leaves you with double-quotes embedded in the string. You can delete the quote characters easily enough with [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-delete), but it's probably easier just to extract the digits from the number and normalize your output format in the first place.

### Normalizing Phone Number Output with a Rails Helper

Consider this example, which leverages the Rails NumberHelper module to format the digits extracted from a string with non-numeric characters:

```
require 'action_view/helpers/number_helper'
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

phone_str = "&quot;(982) 555-1212&quot;]"
number_to_phone phone_str.delete("^0-9"), area_code: true
#=> "(982) 555-1212"
```

This bypasses the need to deal with the HTML entities at all, because you're only concerned with the digits in the string. There are certainly other ways to extract digits, and other ways to format phone numbers, but this should certainly get you started.